# How to use Socket.io in FeathersJS service?

Tags: angular, express, websocket, socket.io, feathersjs

I am trying to implement Socket.io into my Feathersjs/Angular application and have established the communication between the front and back ends.

I understand that the configuration in app.js sets up the server to communicate via WebSockets, but I am not understanding how to use it within a Service that is generated via `feathersjs`.

How can I access the socket.io configuration within the service?

Here is my current code that works:

**on the server in app.js**

```
// Set up Plugins and providers
app.configure(express.rest());
app.configure(socketio(function(io) {
  io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    socket.emit('backend-notification', { text: 'A client connected!' });
    socket.on('frontend-notification', function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  });

  // Registering Socket.io middleware
  io.use(function (socket, next) {
    // Exposing a request property to services and hooks
    socket.feathers.referrer = socket.request.referrer;
    next();
  });
}));
```

**on the frontend in app.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const socket = socketIo('http://localhost:3000');

    socket.on('backend-notification', (data) => {
      console.log(data);
      socket.emit('frontend-notification', { text: 'My frontend-notification!' });
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common way is to also use [Feathers on the client](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client.html) which allows you to transparently access the services on the server. The direct usage of services via a websocket is [documented in the direct connection API for Socket.io](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/client/socketio.html#direct-connection):

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const socket = socketIo('http://localhost:3000');

    socket.on('message create', (message) => {
      console.log('New message created', message);
    });

    socket.emit('create', 'message', {
      text: 'This is a new message'
    }, (error, message) => {
      console.log('New message created via socket', message);
    });
  }
```